# Проверка наличия значения переменной в массиве. JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, extjs

Вопрос (как мне кажется) просто до невозможности.
Есть массив `excludeTypes` в котором один элемент: `["21"]`.
Есть переменная `procedure_types` в которую попадаются разные числовые значения.
Мне нужно написать условие при котором если excludeTypes содержит значение `procedure_types`, то будут выполняться определенные действия.
Как в JS выглядит такое условие?
`excludeTypes.includes(procedure_types)` выдаёт ошибку, при этом по отдельности они оба содержат `21`.

Comment: Вам ниже в ответе намекают, что типы значений должны совпадать. Если одно число, а другое строка, то `includes` вернёт `false`.

Comment: У ответов на Ваши вопросы слева есть значок "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const excludeTypes = ["21"];
const procedure_types_number = 21;
console.log(excludeTypes.includes(procedure_types_number));
const procedure_types_string = "21";
console.log(excludeTypes.includes(procedure_types_string));
```

Comment: благодарю за подсказку!

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужно написать условие при котором если `excludeTypes` содержит значение `procedure_types`, то будут выполняться определенные действия. Как в JS выглядит такое условие?

```
excludeTypes.includes(String(procedure_types))
```

То есть, раз в массиве строки - и проверяемые значения надо приводить к строковому типу.

---

> `excludeTypes.includes(procedure_types)` выдаёт ошибку, при этом по отдельности они оба содержат `21`.

Предлагаю массив `excludeTypes` преобразовать в объект.

Плюсы такого решения:

- это устранит необходимость выполнять явное приведение типа значений
  (проверки значений `'21'` и `21` будут давать одинаковый результат)
- ускорится выполнение проверок
  (хотя эффект будет ощутим только если их будет много)
- выражение условия с оператором `if` упростится до

  ```
  if (excludeTypes[procedure_types]) { .... }
  ```

Пример с преобразованием в объект через `reduce`:

```js
const excludeTypes = ['21'].reduce(
  (rslt, t) => ((rslt[t] = true), rslt)
, Object.create(null)); 

let procedure_types = '21'; 
console.log(excludeTypes[procedure_types]);

procedure_types = 21; 
console.log(excludeTypes[procedure_types]);
```

В примере используется обычный базовый объект без прототипа (точнее, с `null` в прототипе) - так сделано для того, чтобы исключить возможное совпадение проверяемых значений с именами прототипных свойств `Object`.

***Нюанс:** Такая реализация подходит только для некоторых типов значений, в первую очередь для `string` и `number` (и по задумке, и по задаче заданного вопроса). Если же возникнет потребность проверять так же  объектные значения, а не только числовые и строковые, то этот способ уже не подойдет - потому что объекты не могут использоваться в роли ключей обычного базового `object`'а.*

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто подсказал про разность типов значений и посоветовал как лучше привести к одному типу.

В итоге реализовал следующим образом:

```
procedure_type = String(procedure_type);
excludeTypes.indexOf(procedure_type) > -1
```

.includes не подходит для браузеров IE (по крайней мере старых версий).